# Subquery em Java HQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

Olá, estou em um projeto que utiliza geolocalização e eu estou fazendo uma funcionalidade para listar as lojas mais próximas do local escolhido pelo usuário. Estou utilizando o banco de dados PostgreSQL e fiz esta query para realizar a busca:

```
SELECT  ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, 
TELEFONE
FROM (
SELECT ID, CIDADE, CNPJ,DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE,
(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(latitude_local_usuario) )
 * cos( radians( loja.lat ) )
 * cos( radians( loja.lon ) - radians(longitude_local_usuario) )
 + sin( radians(latitude_local_usuario) )
 * sin( radians( loja.lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM loja

) x
GROUP BY ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE, DISTANCIA
HAVING DISTANCIA < distacia_raio_usuario
ORDER BY DISTANCIA ASC;
```

Com essa query eu consigo realizar a busca perfeitamente executando-a diretamente no banco de dados. Pelo java eu estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
TypedQuery<Estudio> query = this.manager
            .createQuery("select ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE" 
                    + "FROM ("
                    + "select ID, CIDADE, CNPJ,DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE,"
                    + "(6371 * acos(" + "cos( radians(:lat) )" + "* cos( radians( loja.lat ) )"
                    + "* cos( radians( loja.lon ) - radians(:lon) )" + "+ sin( radians(:lat) )"
                    + "* sin( radians( loja.lat ) ) " + ")" + ") AS distancia" 
                    + "FROM loja) x"
                    + "GROUP BY ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE, DISTANCIA"
                    + "HAVING DISTANCIA < 5" + "ORDER BY DISTANCIA ASC;", Loja.class);

query.setParameter("lat", lat);
    query.setParameter("lon", lon);
    return query.getResultList();
```

Porém, estou recebendo o seguite erro:

```
  ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (default task-18) line 1:84: unexpected token: select: line 1:84: unexpected token: select
```

Não sei o por que do erro, mas rodando a query abaixo funciona normalmente:

```
  TypedQuery<Estudio> query = this.manager.createQuery("select l from Loja l",
            Loja.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TypedQuery<Estudio> query = this.manager
            .createQuery("select ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE" 
                    + "FROM (" ...
```

Você está concatenando strings para construir um comando SQL e isso pode levar a alguns resultados inesperados. No caso acima observe que o campo **TELEFONE** e a keyword **FROM** serão concatenados numa única palavra **TELEFONEFROM**, gerando erros de sintaxe no SQL final gerado:

```
select ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONEFROM (select ID, CIDADE, CN ...
```

Defina espaços em branco no final da String em cada linha para evitar o problema.
Aconselho também alternar para o uso de **StringBuilder** quando fizer várias operações de concatenação de string:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("select ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE "); 
sql.append("FROM ( "); 
... // Observe o espaço em branco no final de cada linha para evitar misturar tokens
TypedQuery<Estudio> query = this.manager
            .createQuery( sql.toString());
```

Comment: Opa muito obrigado pelo seu retorno, resolveu parcialmente o meu problema. Descobri que o hql não aceita subquery após um FROM,aceita apenas como um elemento do select ou em um WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Como o o hql não aceita subquery após um FROM, apenas como um elemento do select ou em um WHERE, tive a idéia de colocar a query dentro de uma stored function e chamá-la através do hql. A stored funtion ficou da seguinte forma:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."retorna_locais_roximos"(IN latitude double precision, IN longitude double precision, IN dist integer)
    RETURNS SETOF bigint
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $function$
SELECT  ID
FROM (
    SELECT ID, CIDADE, CNPJ,DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE,
    (6371 * acos(
     cos( radians(LATITUDE) )
     * cos( radians( loja.lat ) )
     * cos( radians( loja.lon ) - radians(LONGITUDE) )
     + sin( radians(LATITUDE) )
     * sin( radians( loja.lat ) ) 
     )
    ) AS distancia
    FROM loja

  ) x
  GROUP BY ID, CIDADE, CNPJ, DESCRICAO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, LAT, LON, NOME, TELEFONE, DISTANCIA
  HAVING DISTANCIA < DIST
ORDER BY DISTANCIA ASC;

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION public."retorna_locais_proximos"(double precision, double precision, integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

E a chamo com o hql desta forma:

```
   StoredProcedureQuery query1 = this.manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("retorna_locais_proximos")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Double.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Double.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .setParameter(1, lat)
    .setParameter(2, lon)
    .setParameter(3, distancia);
```

Funcionou bem, só não sei se é o mais correto a se fazer.

Esta Stored Function retorna apenas os ids dos locais, após isso eu posso fazer uma query mais simples para buscar as lojas pelo id.